# How is String.fromCharCode() implemented?

Tags: javascript, string

```
var x = String.fromCharCode(65);

console.log(x);  //returns "A"
```

It accepts an integer and returns corresponding character (string), but that character's code is exactly equal to the input!

What happens under the hood here? Does it really just returns what it accepted? or is there any additional logic?

Comment: You can have a look at the specification: http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.3.2.

Answer (score 2):

have a look @ [spidermonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Getting_SpiderMonkey_source_code) source code

fromCharCode is defined in [jsstr.cpp](https://github.com/havocp/hwf/blob/master/deps/spidermonkey/jsstr.cpp)

it uses a `unitStringTable` for the mapping. The table is defined via preprocessor directives...

Answer (score 0):

I believe it just maintains a dictionary of ASCII codes and return character {value} for input integer{key}

Answer (score 0):

`fromCharCode` is used to convert a Unicode number into a character. Unicode `65` is character `A`. So `String.fromCharCode(65)` returns `A`.

`What happens under the hood here?`

The implementation may be `HashMap` with key-value pair, where Unicode value is mapped to corresponding character or it may be `switch` statement which takes `Unicode` and returns `character`.

Pseudocode of implementation using `switch`:

```
function fromCharCode(*args)
{
   return args.map(unicodeToChar).join('')
}

function unicodeTochar(unicode)
{
   switch(unicode)
   {
      //something

      case 65:
        return 'A'
      case 66:
        return 'B'

     //something
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I know what it does! I am interested about how it's implemented... (in JS interpreter)

Comment: False, try `String.fromCharCode(949, 769)`